# Virtual Machine from Employer / Client on personal hardware

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc, virtual-server-2005-r2

is it possible to use a Virtual Machine that is connected to a domain, without having the host machine on that domain ?

Example.
I have a laptop, we'll call it Dancer. (Laptop Dancer, geddit ?) running Windows 7 Ultimate. Can I run a VM on there that has a corporate installation, development tools, office environment, applications, data, etc., and have that machine able to access the network (when in the office), or the internet (when at home), without having the corporate client being able to affect the configuration and operation of Dancer ?

I want to be be responsible for the configuration, and operation and security of Dancer, but want to be able to use that hardware to develop on software that the client has licenced, installed, configured and cared for, and be able to hand the VM VHD's back at the end of the contract without them worrying that licences from their software have been installed on my laptop.

All virtual technologies, whether MS's offering's or other, such as VirtualBox, or VMWare will be considered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to use a Virtual Machine that is connected to a domain, without having the host machine on that domain ?

Yes. Domain membership is software and independent of the, virtual or not, hardware.

Of course the virtualisation platform will need to provide a network port that the guest can used to talk to the domain.